# Make unaccept/re-accept pairs of events cancel each other

Tags: feature-request, reputation-display

When an answer is unaccepted and then re-accepted again within a short period of time, there is no visible record of it (and I think this is the right thing to do). However, it looks like a vote in the middle prevents the unaccept and re-accept from cancelling each other. It would be nice to cancel the two events visually even with a vote in the middle.

[image: Unaccept/Accept pair]

Comment: This also happens with unupvote/upvote events. But if they were merged, it would cause a discrepancy in the http://stackoverflow.com/reputation page on when the event actually occurred.